# django admin interface - how do I collapse/expand object details in the change list view?

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to be able to collapse and expand object details when showing objects in the django admin change list view. 
For example, for an order, I would like the order list to first appear as:

+ id: 1, name: John Smith 
+ id: 2, name: Jane Doe

And then when the user expands one order:

- id: 1, name: John Smith 
  address: 321 Oaktree Drive, LA, CA 
+ id: 2, name: Jane Doe

inline objects won't work, because the order does not have a foreign key to itself. If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override/extend both the template (`ModelAdmin.change_list_template`) and the view (`ModelAdmin.changelist_view`). The original view accepts `extra_context`, so you can easily add whatever you need. See [contrib.admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/) for more details.